# i tried to connect mongodb with restful web services in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jira-rest-api

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class Mongodbconnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        String connectPoint = client.getConnectPoint();
        System.out.println(connectPoint);
        client.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why jira-rest-api tag?

Comment: Hi bharani m, welcome to [so]. Can you please clairfy what your question is?

Comment: i try to connect mongodb in eclipse ,but my mongodb connection is failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");
```

Comment: I tried the coding in  web application, but code is not running in eclipse